# Report showing column name where should be showing value of the field in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am currently developing a report using SSRS. I have a column called 'FROM' and it is INT data type. I am setting the field correctly but somehow it shows 'from' in the report.

I set up the expression like this: `=Fields!from.Value` and I also tried setting category to number. But somehow it shows 'from' in the preview. I checked my SP and it returns 5000 for the From column. lease let me know how can I solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, are you saying its always displaying the string "from"? Trying adding a new column with that field in it to check where the issue lies.

Comment: To assist we somehow need more information as from the little you have shared it seems it should work.

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of your code where you are setting the value in tablix.